# checking users html form info with PHP on same page

Tags: php, html, forms, if-statement

I am trying to write a simple html form which requires the user to enter the correct email and password, using $_SERVER as the action for my form. I do not want to send the POST info to another php page, but I want to do it on the same page instead.

I have set two variables, $correct_email and $correct_password.

Here is the form;

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">
        <label for="eml">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="eml" id="eml" required>
        <br>
        <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" required>
        <br>
        <input type="hidden" name="checkMe" value="12345">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Here is what I am trying to get work in PHP

```
$correct_email = "(my personal email)";
$correct_password = "password"]; 

if ($_POST['eml']) == $correct_email && ($_POST['pwd']) == $correct_password {

    echo "<h1>You are logged in</h1>";



} else {

    echo "<h1>error</h1>";


}
```

It is not working, please help! I am also unclear on whether the PHP should come before or after the form.

Also, I would like to have the form be cleared from view, on the page, when the correct info is entered.

Thanks so much

Comment: $correct_password = "password"];  maybe the last ] should not be there

Comment: if ($_POST['eml']) == $correct_email && ($_POST['pwd']) == $correct_password

this if statement is also seems not correct

Comment: could you give me some advice on the if statement Met Br?

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the name of the submit button - never call anything "submit" in a form
2. Put the test at the top
3. You had issues with the  `(` and `)` in the test
4. Also an issue with a `]` after "password"

```html
<?php

if ($_POST["subBut"] === "Submit") {
  $correct_email = "(my personal email)";
  $correct_password = "password"; 
  if ($_POST['eml'] == $correct_email && $_POST['pwd'] == $correct_password) {
    echo "<h1>You are logged in</h1>";
  } else {
    echo "<h1>error</h1>";
  }
}
else {
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER[" PHP_SELF "]); ?>">
  <label for="eml">Email:</label>
  <input type="email" name="eml" id="eml" required>
  <br>
  <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" required>
  <br>
  <input type="hidden" name="checkMe" value="12345">
  <input type="submit" name="subBut" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: when I add the form into the code, the web page works, but when I add in the php, I get an error and the page does not load